# install ubuntu got stuck on prepare to install

Tags: system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu I marked both "download updates" & "install 3rd party soft" from last 1/2 hour the mouse pointer is rotating. I am connected to mobile broadband connection.

what should I do now?

Comment: Be patient. It shouldn't take more than an hour but I wouldn't start worrying until a couple hours.

Comment: Yaa now its installing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only a problem if the mouse pointer completely stops rotating. So you're fine, I guess.